# Anyone know how to get pycharm's dracula scheme onto pythons idle

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, color-scheme

Does anyone know how to get the python dracula scheme onto idle, i think idle requires rgb colours and i cannot find the dracula one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a Darcula theme file right here on [Github](https://gist.github.com/AndBondStyle/4951e36afd0d939f54870ed553ea350d).

> Installation:
>
> 1. Ensure IDLE is closed
> 2. Find `.idlerc` or `idlelib` folder somwhere in your home / user / python directory
>    Common locations: `C:\Users\.idlerc` - `C:\Users\%user%\.idlerc` - `Python\Lib\idlelib` - `/home/.idlerc`
> 3. Edit / create `config-highlight.cfg` or `config-highlight.def` file and paste provided config
> 4. Open IDLE and go to `Options > Configure > Highlighting`
> 5. Select "Darcula" theme under "Custom" or "Built-in" option (depending on 3rd step filename)

`config-highlight.cfg`:

```
[Darcula]
normal-foreground = #A9B7C6
normal-background = #2B2B2B
definition-foreground = #A9B7C6
definition-background = #2B2B2B
keyword-foreground = #CC7832
keyword-background = #2B2B2B
builtin-foreground = #8888C6
builtin-background = #2B2B2B
string-foreground = #008080
string-background = #2B2B2B
comment-foreground = #808080
comment-background = #2B2B2B
cursor-foreground = #BBBBBB
error-foreground = #A9B7C6
error-background = #532B2E
hit-foreground = #A9B7C6
hit-background = #155221
hilite-foreground = #A9B7C6
hilite-background = #214283
break-foreground = #A9B7C6
break-background = #3A2323
console-foreground = #007E09
console-background = #2B2B2B
stdout-foreground = #BBBBBB
stdout-background = #2B2B2B
stderr-foreground = #FF6B68
stderr-background = #2B2B2B
```

Comment: GREAT but for soem reason the custom theme is unopenable